# JS - Regex Replace Duplicate Letters

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have these strings:

- Balloon
- DDuupplliiccaattee
- Noodle

I know how to replace all duplicate characters, but that's not what I'm after. I **don't** want Balloon to become Balon, for example. I **only** want to replace if the full string is a duplicate, such as *DDuupplliiccaattee* becoming *Duplicate*... Keeping Balloon and Noodle as they are.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
/\b((.)\2)+\b/
```

Breakdown:

`\b` - matches start word boundary

`((.)\2)+` - match 1 or more groups of duplicate characters

`\b` - matches end word boundary

Answer (score 3):

If you want to recognize a word made up entirely of duplicate characters you can use the regex

```
/\b(?:(.)\1)+\b/
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eG2zO9/1)